# git для проекта с большой иерархией

Tags: git

Имеется проект который имеет сложную иерархию версий и подверсий, которые разрабатываются и поддерживаются параллельно. На данный момент в качестве системы управления версиями используется svn. Подходит ли в таком случае git как альтернатива? Насколько я понимаю, в репозитории git все крутится вокруг одной главной ветки, а все параллельные, в итоге, сливаются в одну, что не накладывается на мой случай.

Comment: Никто не ограничивает вас ветками в гите, более того, эта главная ветка (master) редко вообще используется. Делают релизную, разработку, сприновые, подветки под задчачи – такая стандартная елочка получается. Но можно и наделать веток под каждую версию и вливать в каждую какую-то задачу

Answer (score 1):

> Насколько я понимаю, в репозитории git все крутится вокруг одной главной ветки, а все параллельные, в итоге, сливаются в одну

технически — нет, не «крутится». «сливать в одну» или работать с разными ветками одновременно — это вопрос исключительно организационный.

> Подходит ли в таком случае git как альтернатива?

если не заострять внимание на том, что термин «ветка» в программах *git* и *svn* описывает довольно разные (во всех отношениях) сущности, то для работы с «ветками» программа *git* подходит гораздо лучше программы *svn*.

---

для иллюстрации стоит привести цитату из [статьи Скота Чакона (Scott Chacon)](http://rezvanov.info/2010/06/21/pochemu-vy-dolzhny-ispolzovat-git-vmesto-subversion.html#section-1), автора книги [“Pro Git”](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2):

> В Git, ветки не ругательное слово - они используются и объединяются очень часто, во многих случаях разработчики будут создавать новую ветку для каждой новой возможности и объединять их между собой по несколько раз в день, и это, как правило, безболезненно. Вот, что в первую очередь поразило меня в Git, и, на самом деле, изменило мой подход к разработке.
>
> Когда вы создаете ветку в Git, это происходит локально и очень быстро.

и ссылку на главу 9 из упомянутой книги: [9.1 Git как клиент](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-Git-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82), [9.2 Миграция на Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Git), где в первую очередь внимание уделено как раз программе *svn*.